# Check if array is not empty with length JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I `console.log(arr)` it shows `[]` but I `console.log(arr.length)` it shows `0`? It's confusing for me, so what is the best way to check if an array contain something?

Comment: arr.length is the best way to check the length of an array

Comment: `[]` _is_ an _empty_ array, and _therefor_ its `length` is 0 – what is confusing about that?

Comment: Iit is completely correct ... Javascript arrays are is zero based indexed

Comment: @CBroe how to check if it's not empty or empty then?

Comment: `if (arr.length === 0) { /* array is empty */ }`

Answer (score 4):

You can check if an array is empty by checking the `length` property:

```
if (arr.length === 0) {
    // arr is empty
}
```

Or, to check if it contains some items:

```
if (arr.length) {
    // arr is not empty
}
```

`console.log(arr)` will show `[]` for an empty array.  That's just how it shows that and a `length` property of `0` means that there are no items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array: ['1','2','3','4'], so if the array is empty it will look like this: []. 
I would do like this:

```
if(arr && arr.length){ console.log('then the array is created and it has value'); }
```